# How can I translate dynamic comma-seperated lists with react-18next?

Tags: reactjs, react-i18next

I have a dynamic comma-seperated list of links with the word "and" instead of a comma at last.

So my List can have these four states:

1. "You can use A."
2. "You can use A and B."
3. "You can use A, B and C."
4. "You can use A, B, C and D."

The dynamic list is rendered in React and now I want to translate it with react-18next and the `Trans`component. But I don't get it.

It should translate the text before the list and the word "and". A, B, C and D are names, which are the same in every language.

```
<Trans>
    <span>
        You can use <>{useLinkList}</>.
    </span>
</Trans>
```

The i18n looks like this in the third case (because of React Fragments):

```
"<0><0><1>You can use <1><0>A</0><1>, </1><2>B</2><3> and </3><4>C</4></1>.</1></0></0>"
```

But how can I get it work with all 4 cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a programmatic solution for your problem, which could lead to some translation/internationalization problems later in the project. These could be:

- A different seperator is common in another language, i.e. ; instead of comma
- "and" is positioned somewhere else

Split the useLinkList in two parts. The first contains a list with ["A"] upto ["A", "B", "C"]. The second part contains only the last Element or is omited. Call the translation function twice to translate "and" as well.

```
// In your component
{t("linkList", {
        elements: [[FirstPart].join(","), lastElement].join(t(" and ")),
})}

// In your locale
{
"linkList": "You can use {{ elements }}.",
" and ": " and "
}
```

A different approach which is more flexible for localization would be to use ICU Messages. If the cases are fixed, an option could be to use a select statement. Here is a [quick guide for the syntax](https://simpleen.io/blog/icu-message-format-guide).

Comment: Thank you very much! This seem to be the best way. I am trying it without ICU Messages but the elements are Listed only as [Object object]. What must I do to get it work with JSX Elements (a-Tags) to get rendered? :)

Comment: I get it work. join can't be used with JSX Elements. I use map and then it worked! But you can't give a translation property a JSX Element. So I am making an own Component with the Linklist and the "and" translation and the other text stay translated in the <Trans> component